# Scala code to replace null values of a column in a dataframe which is in form of list

Tags: list, scala, replace

I am trying to replace null values from the dataset which is in form of a list. I used the below code still I didn't give me the desired result. What should I do?

I am using the below code:

```
 val mergedDS =customerDS.join(acctstep1,Seq("customerId"),"outer")
    .withColumn("numberAccounts", 'numberAccounts.cast("Int"))
    .withColumn("totalBalance",'totalBalance.cast("Long"))

  // Lets remove all the accounts with missing values for customers
  val customerAccountOutputDS = mergedDS.as[CustomerAccountOutput].na.fill(0).show(false)
  print(customerAccountOutputDS)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO3T5.png)

Comment: Can you also  give your desired result?

Comment: @QuickSilver in place of null values which are populated now it should have empty square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
object DefaultEmptyArray {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = List(Bean(List("A","B")),Bean(null),Bean(List("C","D")))
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
    val df  = spark.createDataFrame(input)

    df.select("inputList")
      .withColumn("outputList",when(col("inputList").isNull,Array[String]()).otherwise(col("inputList")))
      .show()
  }
}

case class Bean( inputList : List[String])
```

Comment: is there any way to do this by pattern matching?

Comment: Everything in Dataframe needs to map to one or the other primitive data type like and pattern would work only on string data type but null values once type cast to string cannot be type cast empty array.

Comment: I am new to scala and the above method seems little complicated to me. My mentor suggested me something like this: "probably pattern match on null values and replace with empty lists potentially". But I am unable to get this too.